# Debug Info: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'IpNetRow2' was corrupted

Tags: c

I have been trying to use *GetIpNetEntry2* and *ResolveIpNetEntry2* functions to get MAC address from a IPv4 in Visual Studio 2017 (SDK 8.1) on Windows 10 (Enterprise 1803). I have been getting:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'IpNetRow2' was corrupted.

by the end of the following function:

```
static int GetMacAddress(SOCKADDR_IN ClientAddr)
{
    MIB_IPNET_ROW2 IpNetRow2 = { 0 };
    DWORD dwBestIfIndex = 0;
    int nRet = -1;

    // Retrieves the index of the interface that has the best route to the client IP address.
    GetBestInterface(inet_addr(inet_ntoa(ClientAddr.sin_addr)), &dwBestIfIndex);
    // Finds MAC address from the local computer
    IpNetRow2.InterfaceIndex = dwBestIfIndex;
    IpNetRow2.Address.si_family = AF_INET;
    IpNetRow2.Address.Ipv4.sin_addr.s_addr = ClientAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;

    nRet = GetIpNetEntry2(&IpNetRow2);
    if (nRet != NO_ERROR)
    {
        // Could not find the MAC address in the cache, lets hit the wire.
        nRet = ResolveIpNetEntry2(&IpNetRow2, NULL);
    }

    return nRet;
}
```

Returned results are valid with `nRet` = 0 and `dwBestIfIndex` = 22.
I have searched as much as I can for a description of how to diagnose the issue; however I have not found any solution that is relevant. The code is so simple and I have on idea on what part of the code would cause such issue.

Comment: I would guess that you are overflowing `MACAddress`. Can't see where though. Anyway, remove the `&` in front of it in `memset`.

Comment: Not sure if this will cause your fault, but notice the discrepancy between `memset(&MACAddress, ...)` and `memcpy(MACAddress, ...)` where I would expect to see the same first argument. Also, it is unclear what your types are in the code, and so does `sizeof` give the size of what you think it is giving?

Comment: @WeatherVane The types are the MS API ones

Comment: @Eugene Sh. `memcpy` and `memset` should take *exactly the same* first argument.

Comment: `memcpy(&IpNetRow2.Address, &ClientAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));` looks suspicious.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is what I said in the first comment

Comment: @Eugene Sh. perhaps your edit was while I was typing.

Comment: I don't see any obvious issue here... Maybe a bigger snippet with the function call help

Comment: What's `strMACAddress`?

Comment: With `MACAddress` being an array, `&MACAddress` and `MACAddress` evaluate to pointers to the same address, with different types.  Using both is poor form, but of little practical import since they are both converted to type `void *` in preparation for the function call anyway.

Comment: Moreover, it is not useful to `memset()` the array contents before overwriting them (all) with `memcpy()`, though it's not actually harmful to do so.

Comment: Not being able to find any issues with anything else, I am inclined to suspect that one of the winsock function calls, `GetIpNetEntry2(&IpNetRow2)` or `ResolveIpNetEntry2(&IpNetRow2, NULL)`, is writing out of bounds.  If so, that would more likely be because something is wrong with the arguments than because the functions are broken, but I've dug about as much into this as I'm prepared to do for the time being.

Comment: ... though there is the question of what `strMACAddress` is and whether it's large enough.  But even if there were an issue there, that does not appear likely to cause corruption of the function's stack frame.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have removed unnecessary variables, but I still get the same `Run-Time Check Failure #2`. `GetIpNetEntry2` function returns successfully. `nRet` is `NO_ERROR`. I am wondering if  it would be something wrong inside `GetIpNetEntry2` function. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Verify that `dwBestIfIndex` has a valid, non-zero value before the call to `GetIpNetEntry2()`. I know it's supposed to return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` if it is, but past experience with Windows return values tells me to advise you the verify the inputs yourself.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thank you for your advice. I have verified that `dwBestIfIndex' is a valid value. BTW, someone stated that this code runs on WIndows 8.1 without the issue. I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017. I am not sure if the environment matters...

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I really appreciate it. Eventually I figured it out. It is not a code issue but a configuration issue. The Struct Member Alignment (Visual Studio Project Property -> C/C++ -> Code Generation) was set to 1 byte which caused the issue. I changed it back to 'Default' then the exception is gone. Learned a lesson. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I really appreciate it. Eventually I figured it out. It is not a code issue but a configuration issue. The Struct Member Alignment (Visual Studio Project Property -> C/C++ -> Code Generation) was set to 1 byte which caused the issue. I changed it back to 'Default' then the exception is gone. Learned a lesson. Thank you.